# Comparing two similar images that contain text

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have pairs of images that look the same for the human eye, but if you zoom in and examine the details - they differ in their pixels - mainly due to different rendering.

I'm looking for an algorithm that could tell whether two images are the same. Using regular pixel by pixel comparison does not work, because there are differences, such as **different anti-aliasing** or **different letter spacing** (which leads to offset in pixels).

Another possible case is where in one image the text can be italic / underline and in the second image not.

Assumptions are:

- Font size is the same for the two images
- Font size can be small and large - from 8px to 30px
- Images have the same size

Here are 2 examples of images containing the same text, rendered a bit differently:

[image]

[image]

Here's an example of two images that are different:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Check https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using SSIM, but as my images can be very small, it does not seem to work that well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know what you're running this process for. I mean, below I'm suggesting a possible use of OCR; of course if you're trying to build an OCR of your own, my suggestion would make no sense at all (I am running with a hunch that you might be trying to automate some kind of browser-rendered UI interfacing).

The different anti-aliasing you can compensate with pre-thresholding or [PSNR](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38065/peak-signal-to-noise-ratio-psnr-in-python-for-an-image) calculation. This assumes that the letters are positioned exactly in the same way.

If the spacing is different (and, even more, if you have different *kernings*) *and* aliasing is different, then I think your best choice is either OCR both images separately and compare the resulting text; or you will have to segment each text line, then realign the images at every letter. Basically you take one vertical slice, one to three pixels wide, from image 1; then get the PSNR values for five different slices of identical size on image 2, aligned with offsets from -2 to +2 (say); the minimum PSNR will give you both the offset adjustment for the following letters and the reliability of the match.

The problem is that if the letters are **really** different, you will no longer be able to reliably calculate the image offsets, so you will be able to tell that "HELLO" and "HILLS" are different, but will not be able to quantify the difference because you'll have lost synch and be unable to compare the two L's. *Unless* you try re-synching with larger offsets (from -2 to +X with X being the width of the wider letter, probably the "W"), but this will be expensive and still error-prone (for example, if comparing "13" with the letter "B", or "LI" with "U", "I." with "L", etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use this as an alternative method for OCR, where I use template matching instead (I use OCR as well, but I prefer having the two methods available for use), since OCR isn't accurate for small images.

Comment: I used the "sliced PSNR" method for OCR'ing small texts (years ago, I worked at the digitisation of the first issues of BURT magazine into searchable PDFs). The brute-force C solution was, once known what the fonts used actually *were*, sequentially compare each "character" with an array of candidate characters. It worked well, if very, VERY slowly. We added trees, probability trigrams and what not. Also, we started using for each letter the average of the last N letters as they appeared in the same scanned image. In the end we did better than Tesseract. I can add the story if you want :-)